# How to select a random number with a certain range and excluded a certain number for n trials using Python

Tags: python

Good day! I having a difficulty in selecting random numbers from 1 to 10. I want to exclude the no 9. in selectin the random numbers. Also i want to repeat the selection for 100 times or trials. I already made a code in selecting random numbers excluded the number 9.

```
from random import choice
x = (random.choice([i for i in range(1,10) if i not in [9]]))
print (x)
```

However, I don't know to repeat this process at 100 times. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Then you need to continue in your educational materials and learn how to write loops.  As there are many existing resources for this, the issue is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Prune I mean yes indeed there are many solutions to many problems on SO but if you remember the times where you started programming figuring new stuff out coming from things you already learned was quite hard. So do this guy a favor and answer his question it is well written. That's what SO is there for: to help people who got stuck!

Comment: @Cedced_Bro: ummmm ... no.  Please review the intro tour.  SO is specifically *not* intended to be a redundant resource.

Answer (score 2):

Just add one more list comprehension:

```
from random import choice
x = [(choice([i for i in range(1,10) if i not in [9]])) for j in range(100)]
print (x)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an underscore as a dummy variable and run it like this:

```
trials = 100
for _ in range(trials):
   x = (random.choice([i for i in range(1,10) if i not in [9]]))
    print(x)
```

You can also do this with a list comprehension:

```
trials = 100
numbers = [(random.choice([i for i in range(1,10) if i not in [9]])) for _ in range(trials)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's good that you're trying to avoid having the list recreated on every loop iteration.

You could define your list (`[i for i in range(1,10) if i not in [9]]`) beforehand (for example, `options = [i for i in range(1,10) if i not in [9]]`) and then in your loop, you just use your defined set (`random.choice(options)`).